# Unable to check write permission on windows directory in perl

Tags: perl

```
if( -w $filename)
```

always returning TRUE if we change write permission of directory through windows

Comment: You may want to give more info: what you tried, how you change permission, ...

Comment: i am checking write permission using above command in perl.

Comment: and i change write permission through windows feature (folder right click: Properties->Security-> Deny permission for write)

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the properties dialog of a windows folder, you will see:

[image]

Comment: i have to only check write permission of folder.